# Changing React UI if API call is/isn't successful

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux

I am writing a `React`+`Redux` app. To make the API calls I am using `Redux` *middleware* that use `fetch` looks like this:

```
const Api = ({dispatch, getState}) => (next) => (action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_FROM_API':
            fetch('https://my-awesome-api/action')
            .then(res => {
                if (res.ok) {
                    return res.json()
                } else {
                    throw Error(`wrong API response: ${res.status}`)
                }
            }).then(jsonData => {
                dispatch({type: 'FETCH_FROM_API_DONE', payload: jsonData})
            }).catch((e) => {
                dispatch({type: 'API_ERROR', payload: e})
            })
            break
        default:
            break
    }

    next(action)
}

export default Api
```

The action is dispatched in a method (in a component) that looks like this:

```
doButtonClick() {
    dispatch({type: 'FETCH_FROM_API'})
}
```

The problem is that in the actual code I have a lot of component that I want to change the state of, based on success/failure in the specific API call. This includes (but isn't limited to):

- Clearing input fields etc. when element is successfully created
- Displaying an error message (inside the specific component) if the API call fails
- Display a loading message (inside the specific component) while the API call is ongoing

There is a general handler for `API_ERROR` events when they are dispatched - but this doesn't solve the main problem that is a strong desire to have a state in the actual component dispatching the API call event.

So far I've come up with two possible solutions. The first is to use callback function(s) - they could be put in the events before dispatching, eg.:

```
dispatch({
    type: 'FETCH_FROM_API',
    success: () => {
        // Handle success
    },
    error: () => {
        // Handle error
    }
})
```

... but this will litter the code (there are many dispatched API calls) with callback functions. The second is to add `Redux` state specific to the separate API calls and have `connect()` it to the component(s) so they can change accordingly - but this will add a lot of extra state.

Is there any proven good way to achieve this?

Comment: Looks to me that the state of those components should probably be moved in the Redux store to allow you to change their state using reducers to listen on the success / failure of API calls.

Comment: how about a lookup table in your store that lists all the failed operations as keys, then create a selector (maybe memoized) that each relevant component can query the relevant operation within this object. for example: `failedOps{fetchTodos: true, saveTodo: true, toggleTodo: false}` and access it like this: `showErrr() && failedtodos.fetchTodos`

Comment: Thanks @Sagivb.g and greto - the main problem using the redux store is that it isn't really a state I want to represent - it's more a change in state. I have an input field with a value/name that is to be saved - but the control doesn't not go away (the user should be able to create multiple items). When the save is successful the input should be cleared and given focus and if the save fails the user should be notified. The notification part is somewhat trivial - the conditional clearing troubles me.